# What is needed on the client machine to deploy .NET software?

Tags: .net, deployment

I am deploying the .Net windows application to client system. Do client need .Net software in his system?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, however if you use the Setup/Deployment project in Visual Studio you can create a Setup.exe that will bootstrap and install the .NET framework for you. However, if you don't do this, then yes there will need to be a .NET framework compatible with your application installed prior to running your application.

Although, it is possible to avoid this if you absolutely need to. This is rare but you can use a tool like Salamander or Xenocode to bundle the framework into your application. However, this is not recommended and only do this if it is a core requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, client needs .net framework of your applications version or upper.

For example if you write your application in .NET 2.0 client needs .NET Framework 2.0 or upper.

Comment: Not quite, you need the framework required by the program itself, a higher version may or may not work.

Comment: What if you use generics and you deploy your application to a machine that has .NET framework 1.1 ? 
I'm telling about backward compatibility. So If client has .NET 3.5 then the application will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the client should has the .NET framework installed in order for the application to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need the CLR on the target machine to run the .net app.